# Active Report 10 TextBox Resize toghether

Tags: c#, activereports

I create table using label and textbox. I write code for textbox resize but it not working correctly. Last text box size does not resize correctly

[image]

Here last textbox size getting infinite

This is my code:

```
private void groupHeader1_BeforePrint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int li = 0;
    for (li = 0; li <= groupHeader1.Controls.Count - 1; li++)
    {
        if (groupHeader1.Controls[li] != null)
        {
            groupHeader1.Controls[li].Height = groupHeader1.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

layout cannot change in BeforePrint event, only in Format event.
if you can share more information about your report and how it works maybe we can help you resolve the issue properly.
[Grapecity](https://www.grapecity.com)

Comment: but when i write code in format event then it not working textbox is not resizing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using groupHeader1.Controls[li].Height, use the name of the Textbox. 
For example, I added a Textbox to the design surface of a section report and then modified the height of that Textbox by using the Textboxes Name Property (TextBox1) in the Detail_Format event.

```
public void Detail_Format() {
//This will modify the height of the Textbox at run-time
this.TextBox1.Height = 5;
}
```

Grapecity Support Team

https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact

Comment: i want textbox and label both resize together, suppose my textbox size increase at run time due to long text then label size also increase as same as textbox.